# How to recover deleted mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql workbench on my server and today I checked just my all schemas are deleted resulting in halt of other application.I am confused how it has  happened.Is there a way to  check who has last  connected to my workbench as few ppl have its access and how can I recover the lost database or there could be another reason for lost of all databases

Comment: I guess you didn't backed up your db?

Comment: If you wanted backups, you would have made them... now it is too late... this is why ppl do back ups before they loose data

Comment: You can check the log to see the SQL action results performed in Workbench. But the database, if not backuped, is gone.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Workbench is a client tool. If you installed it on a database server, then perhaps you should be checking who was logged on to the db server and that will be appropriately logged by the O/S. You might also want to review your security policy because it sounds like you might be sharing passwords and review which user accounts have DROP privilege on the databases.

Your databases might not show in Workbench if the connection is not properly configured (but the applications not working would suggest otherwise).